# is it possible to use sharepoint server-side code inside the search core web part xstl?

Tags: xslt, search-results

is it possible to use sharepoint server-side code inside the search core web part xstl?
I have to join the search web part data and data from a custom list.

I am trying to achieve this functionality:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can't use server side code inside the xslt.
The only way to achieve your goal is by extending the core search web part.

By extending the core search results web part you can take control over the query (using server side code) and make your own query or just append your query using FQL (Fast Query Language) or keyword query. This way you can join the search web part data and data from a custom list.

Example:

```
   [ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
    public class JoinListsCoreResultWebPart : CoreResultsWebPart
    {
protected override void ConfigureDataSourceProperties()
        {
        //Just Append Search Query with your query
            this.AppendedQuery = "your join query for custom list";

            base.ConfigureDataSourceProperties();
        }
    }
}
```

Check out this post:
http://sqlgoogler.blogspot.co.il/2012/01/extend-search-core-result-web-part-with.html

And this one:
http://consultingblogs.emc.com/mattlally/archive/2011/12/29/sharepoint-2010-custom-my-search-core-results.aspx

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks a lot for your help. I will try your suggestion. I will be back soon.

Comment: have you tried this solution?

Comment: Hi Alex, I gave it a try but it seemed difficult to achieve it. I found another solution though that helped me. I created an xslt function and I used that in my search result web part. Thanks a lot though for your help.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who might fase the same issue this is how I solved it:

I created a xslt function. I used this link [create-your-own-xslt-functions-using-c](http://www.helpmeonsharepoint.com/2012/05/create-your-own-xslt-functions-using-c.html).
it is a long blog that is why I am not pasting any code here. However, if you need help let me know.
I hope it helps someone else.